# Iterating xml using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery and I have the following xml response:

```
<root>
   <case>
      <ckey>100</ckey>
      <case-description>something</case-description>
      <issue>
         <ikey>issue-one</ikey>
         <ikey-description>issue-two</ikey-description>
      </issue>
   </case>
   <case>
      <ckey>101</ckey>
      <case-description>something</case-description>
      <issue>
         <ikey>issue-one</ikey>
         <ikey-description>issue-two</ikey-description>
      </issue>
   </case>
</root>
```

The summary of the above xml is that each `<case>` will have `<issue>` nodes under it. I have to iterate over each and every `<case>` and then issues `<issue>` under it and add them  to an array which can be used to populate the cases(`<case>`) and 
issues(`<issue>`) under it in a jquery datatable.

I tried with the following code, but I am not getting the required format. 
Can anybody help me out?

```
 $(".dataTables_scrollBody").find(".details-control").on("click", function() {

    var $CaseLkupTables = $(soapGetResultslist.responseXml).find("case");

    $CaseLkupTables.each(function(index, event) {
        var $event = $(event),
            addData = [];

        $event.children().each(function(i, child) {


            addData.push($(child).text());

            var issueNodes = XmlUtil.selectNodes(child, "//issue");
            for (var i = 0; i < issueNodes.length; i++) {

                var idvalue = XmlUtil.xmlToString(XmlUtil.selectSingleNode(issueNodes[i], "//ISSUEID"))
            }
        });

        table.data(addData);
    });

    var xyz = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
    alert("vvv " + xyz[0]);


    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);
    alert("row data " + row.data()[0]);


    $.each(issueNodes, function(index, value) {
        console.log(value)

    });



    console.log(row.data());
    $tds = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)");


    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    } else {
        // Open this row
        var td = $(this).parent('td');
        //alert("Child data "+  table.row( td ).data());
        //  row.child(format(issueNodes) ).show();
        //  expandhideContact( string );

        row.child(issueNodes).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
});
```

With the above code,  I am able to get only case nodes info, but unable to get issue nodes info under each case node.

Comment: XML isn't HTML; You should process it by the function `$.parseXML()`. For more details, see [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/).

Comment: @ Chayim Friedman, I have added raw code, not the real one to avoid confusion as our contains more customized code.

Comment: But you're using that function?

Comment: @ Chayim Friedman, Yeah. You are correct. Any kind of raw that you can assist with?

Comment: @Ashok.N Can you display us the full code?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, I have added full code to the question.

Comment: @Ashok.N What is the variable `soapGetResultslist.responseXml`? Please display us the code there he gets its value.

Comment: @Chayim Friedman, That's the actual xml response that we receive as response. I have already added it to the question. Please take a look.

Comment: That is a string? If so, you didn't call `$.parseXML()`!

Comment: @Chayim Friedman, That's already in xml format. No need to use `$.parseXML()` I believe.

Comment: @Ashok.N No, is this is a string, you should use `$.parseXML()`. It'll return this as node.

Comment: The following statement is working for me: `caseCount = $(soapGetResultslist.responseXml).find("case").length`. I could able to get all the case nodes now. The problem is with the issue nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this implementation

```
 var x ="<root><case><ckey>100</ckey><case-description>something</case-description><issue><ikey>issue-one</ikey><ikey-description>issue-two</ikey-description></issue></case><case><ckey>101</ckey><case-description>something</case-description><issue><ikey>issue-one</ikey><ikey-description>issue-two</ikey-description></issue></case></root>";

    $($.parseXML(x)).find('case').each(function(index){
                var ckey = $(this).find('ckey').text();
                var description = $(this).find('case-description').text();
                var issueikey = $(this).find('issue').find('ikey').text(); var issueikeyDescription = $(this).find('issue').find('ikey-description').text();
                console.log(ckey,description,issueikey,issueikeyDescription);
            });
```

Comment: Awesome!! perfect!! That's what I was looking for. +1 for perfect solution.